# httr POST API request but missing xml parameter

Tags: xml, r, rcurl, httr

I am trying to connect to the XML API for IBM Silverpop using `httr`, but I am running into a 'missing XML parameter' problem. I tried using the test harness provided by Silverpop to see if the requests I am sending is different in comparison to what I send via `httr`, but haven't found anything to help me.

Following is the `XML` body I send when using the **test harness** which succeeds:

```
<Envelope><Body>
<Login>
<USERNAME>My Email</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>My password</PASSWORD>
</Login>
</Body></Envelope>
```

Using Chrome to inspect the **request headers** (using `CTRL + SHIFT + I`):

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:225
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:api3.silverpop.com
Origin:null
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

Again, using Chrome to inspect **response headers**:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 04 Dec 2015 12:15:34 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Using `httr`, I construct my request as follows:

```
library(httr)

ibmUrl <- "api3.silverpop.com/XMLAPI"

body1 <- "<Envelope><Body>
<Login>
<USERNAME>My Email</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>My password</PASSWORD>
</Login>
</Body></Envelope>"

test1 <- POST(url = ibmUrl, body = body1, verbose(), content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
```

Using `verbose()` shows the following being sent and received:

```
-> POST /XMLAPI HTTP/1.1
-> Host: api3.silverpop.com
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/0.9.3 httr/1.0.0
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
-> Content-Length: 132
-> 
>> <Envelope><Body>
>> <Login>
>> <USERNAME>My Email</USERNAME>
>> <PASSWORD>My password</PASSWORD>
>> </Login>
>> </Body></Envelope>

<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 13:29:55 GMT
<- Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
<- Content-Type: text/xml
<- Content-Length: 255
```

But when I inspect the response from the API using `content()`, I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Envelope>
  <Body>
    <RESULT>
      <SUCCESS>false</SUCCESS>
    </RESULT>
    <Fault>
      <Request/>
      <FaultCode/>
      <FaultString>Missing 'xml'parameter</FaultString>
      <detail>
        <error>
          <errorid>52</errorid>
          <module/>
          <class>SP.API</class>
          <method/>
        </error>
      </detail>
    </Fault>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

How come?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the answer - although not quite sure why this works and my original attempt shown in the question did not...

This was my original code:

```
test1 <- POST(url = ibmUrl, body = body1, 
verbose(), content_type("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))
```

All I had to change was the content_type to 'text/xml'.

```
test1 <- POST(url = ibmUrl,
        body = body1, verbose(), content_type("text/xml"))
```

And it works... But would be thankful if anybody could chime in and clarify why this solves the problem...

Comment: @hadley (embarrassed), but I was only copying the raw form of request being sent by my browser. I thought the same would be sent using httr?
Thanks for replying.

Comment: I know this is old but I just stumbled about a very similar problem and it turns out, they seem to only accept "text/xml" and not "application/xml". As such content_type_xml() fails with the curious error message "missing xml parameter" :)

Comment: Also, to answer the question here, straight from the xml_api_developer_guide for Silverpop: "If passing the XML as a URL parameter (xml=) you must URL encode the XML and specify that it is URL encoded (Content- Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded)." So I assume that is what the testharness does.

Comment: @DeVadder the question was old, but the info you shared is certainly valuable - thanks!

Comment: @info_seekeR Yeah but the people of the future might still stumble upon it and wonder the same things. And six months is not really that long especially considering that our Silverpop overlords did not change anything about the Api or its documentation in the time.

Comment: Wow, this saved my day. Even I was stuck on the same issue, Although I was trying using php. All I changed is `application/xml` to `text/xml`. Thanks a lot @info_seekeR